# Live Server extension not working when workspace is other than the current project

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I am using the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension for VS code, but the problem is that when I write code in HTML, the browser does not reload automatically. i.e. I have to open the browser and refresh it manually to see the changes.

This whole thing was working fine when I was using VS Code, but since I have shifted to VS Code Insiders, the auto reload thing is broken.

**PS.** I have autosave turned on and I made no changes in the setting.

Edit: I have found out that the extension works correctly when the project folder is open as the root folder. But when I open one folder beneath the project folder (i.e. the workspace where I keep all my project folders), the extension breaks. Any way to make this work with a custom workspace root?

Comment: Hi Anupam Raut, Yet Live Server for vscode isn't supported for multi-root workspace.

https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 weeks now. And just fixed it today. I installed v5.6.1 and it didn't work. I'm using windows 10, 64 bit, Did some research and change some config with no luck. So I tried to downgrade the version to v5.6.0 and it worked! Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

*I solved the problem openning the workspace file and putting first the serving folder on the list of folders:*

Previous

```
{
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "folder-01"
    },
    {
        "path": "folder-02"
    },
    {
        "path": "folder-03"
    }
],
"settings": {
    "liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "folder-01"
}
```

}

Post

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "folder-02"
        },
        {
            "path": "folder-01"
        },
        {
            "path": "folder-03"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "folder-02"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem in vs code.  only I moved  the new folder to top location
with draging in explorer. and  ran the file with "Open with live server".  and it's ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).